# Simulating having multiple Control Flows in a SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSIS package that in its Control Flow I have quite lot of Data flows. To be able to organise them, I have wrapped the related Data flows into Groups. For example I have 5 groups as below which each one has got on average 8 Data flows. For example:

Students Group (includes a number of Data flows)

Courses Group (includes a number of Data flows)

Institutes Group (includes a number of Data flows)

Enrollments Group (includes a number of Data flows)

...

Now I see the need for adding more and more Data flows to each group is growing! Each of these groups are already big and adding more Data flows only make them more crowded and more difficult to maintain.

Based on my research there is no way to have multiple Control flows in a package, otherwise I would put each of the Data flows above in a Control flow, e.g.: one Control flow for Students, one for Courses, etc.

I know I can create a package for each area, for example one package for Students, etc, but I prefer to avoid adding two many packages as much as possible.

Do you have any idea how I can organise them in a package in a sustainable and clean manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use groups, use Sequence Containers. That way, you can have the ones you want to run in parallel in the same container, and then have a subsequent container kicked off with additional data flows.

You can't have multiple Control Flows, but you can have multiple packages, and you can have a ton of containers to give you more control over the flow.